# c# get complete URL with "#"

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have run into a trivial(?) problem when trying to get the whole URL of a c# page.

The url contains the "#"-link ref char. And i would like that to when I grab the URL

Eg. http://localhost/site/page.aspx?var=1&var=2#link

I have tried Request.URL, Request.Querystring etc, it only returns up to the "#"-char.

Is there any way to grab even the last part?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need such functionality? Maybe there's an alternative way of solving your problem.

Comment: Its because creator of the page has used querystrings to pass passwords, and thus disabling a password containing #, stupid, I know

Comment: You should avoid passing passwords in query strings, as doing so allows you to log in from a query string without a post. Some browser add-ins (such as Google web accelerator) can hit these thinking that they are navigation, rather than actions. As a general rule GETs should just display stuff, anything that changes data or state should be POST

Comment: Is 'disabling a password containing #' the problem? I'm sure you could escape/encode characters like # in a password to get around that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that # specified an anchor in the page, so the *browser* sees:

> http://localhost/site/page.aspx?var=1&var=2

And then looks in the page for

```
<a name="link">anchor</a>
```

As this is client side you need to escape the # from the URL - you can't get it on the server because the browser's already stripped it off.

Answer (score 8):

That is not possible using server code only. The part after the # is not sent in the request at all, it never leaves the browser.

If you want the part after the # you have to copy it using Javascript before the request is sent to the server, and put the value in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the stuff after the # isn't sent to the server. I'm pretty sure i made a test with an ajax-app some years ago where the url could be copied and sent to people without javascript by only modifiying the stuff after the # in the url when browsing around with javascript enabled.

That was in PHP and the browser was probably IE6.