# How to get # value from query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Please help me to get query string value from the URL.

```
http://test.com/test.aspx#id=test
```

I tried to access with

```
Request.QueryString["id"]
```

Its getting null value.Please suggest how to access id from the url.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with everyone that the `#` should be a `?`, but just FYI:

Note it isn't actually possible get the anchor off the URL, for example:

> `http://test.com/test.aspx#id=test`

The problem is that # specified an anchor in the page, so the *browser* sees:

> `http://test.com/test.aspx`

And then looks in the page for

```
<a id="test">Your anchor</a>
```

As this is client side you need to escape the # from the URL - you can't get it on the server because the browser's already stripped it off.

If you want the part after the # you have to copy it using Javascript before the request is sent to the server, and put the value in the querystring.

More info here [c# get complete URL with "#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322108/c-sharp-get-complete-url-with)

Answer (score 8):

A query string starts with a question mark `?` not a hash `#`.

Try:

```
http://test.com/test.aspx?id=test
```

Using a hash, you're asking to jump to a named anchor within the document, not providing a query string

Answer (score 7):

Your URL is not valid.

```
 http://test.com/test.aspx#id=test
```

refers to a *bookmark* named `id=test`.

You should use

```
http://test.com/test.aspx?id=test
```

And then `Request.QueryString["id"]` will work.

Comment: Its api call so i can't do anything.

Comment: I see you have come a long way @HenkHolterman. With 193K reputation and in the top 0.05% or SO you probably now know what an API call is haha.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to use it as hash tag you can use:

```
string value = Request.Url.ToString().Split('#')[1];
```

with this code, you will have your hash tag value.

Answer (score 2):

Isnt it supposed to be?

```
http://test.com/test.aspx?id=test
```