# How to read the query string when it contains unencoded data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, url, request

I have the below asp.net page which accepts a "url" query string key whose value can be an un-encoded url:

```
http://localhost:4104/WebSiteForTest/TinyUrl.aspx?url=http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=life&oq=life&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2803373l2803701l2l2803826l4l4l0l0l0l0l188l453l0.3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=94681dc4659502d1&biw=1680&bih=883
```

Now from this page, how would that be possible to read the text after ".aspx?"?

I checked the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri property and it only showed

```
"http://localhost:4104/WebSiteForTest/TinyUrl.aspx?url=http://www.google.co.uk/"
```

I also checked with the Request.QueryString with the below code:

```
 private void getQueryString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var queryStringCount = Request.QueryString.Keys.Count;

        for (int keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < queryStringCount; keyIndex++)
        {
            sb.Append(Request.QueryString.Keys[keyIndex]).Append("=").Append(Request.QueryString[keyIndex]);
            if (keyIndex != (queryStringCount - 1))
            {
                sb.Append("&");
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the code after "#" doesn't appear in any query string.

how would that be possible to read the text after ".aspx?"?

if you say it's not possible, how Google uses "#" in their url then when you search for something?!

http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&site=&q=life&oq=life&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3317l3630l0l3755l4l4l0l0l0l0l125l391l3.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=94681dc4659502d1&biw=1680&bih=849

Thanks,

Comment: can a querystring parameter contain unencoded data?

Comment: @Jodrell, it can e.g. http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&site=&q=life&oq=life&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3317l3630l0l3755l4l4l0l0l0l0l125l391l3.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=94681dc4659502d1&biw=1680&bih=849

Comment: @M.Babcock, please read the question again.

Comment: I still don't see any unencoded data in the query string but I think the answer you are looking for is in the Javascript of the google search page.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to get value after anchor on server side, you can check this with fiddler or something similar, you should deal with this on client. Browser simply strips all after anchor.

[Retrieving Anchor Link In URL for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net)

[c# get complete URL with "#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322108/c-sharp-get-complete-url-with)

Update:

I don't know how google exactly do this, but if you look with fiddler after initial request there goes another without #, here is a fidller log for request from your question :

[image]

so my advice is look with fiddler how google do this, or maybe ask another question

Comment: if not possible then how comes google uses # in their urls when you search something?!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Request.QueryString](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp)

```
http://localhost:4104/WebSiteForTest/TinyUrl.aspx?url=http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=life&oq=life&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2803373l2803701l2l2803826l4l4l0l0l0l0l188l453l0.3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=94681dc4659502d1&biw=1680&bih=883
```

> 

`<%=Request.QueryString("url")%>` will get the ?url parameter

Comment: it doesn't. it only gets the part until #.

Comment: and this behaviour is by design, browser cuts all after anchor, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using C# to do this. You can easily get the parameters and their values by iterating through the request object.  Or in this case, since you know the name of the parameter, simply do this:

String url = Request.QueryString["url"];

More information on [iterating through your request parameters can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx).

Comment: Like I said, the text after # does not appear in the Request.QueryString as a key.

Answer (score 0):

The `Uri` Type works as well.

```
String yourHttpUri ="....";
Uri yourURI = new Uri(yourHttpUri);
yourURI.query // "?url=http://www.google.co.uk/"
yourURI.fragment // "#hl=en&q=life&oq=life&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2803373l2803701l2l2803826l4l4l0l0l0l0l188l453l0.3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=94681dc4659502d1&biw=1680&bih=883"
```

Edit:

Have you tried `Request.Url.ToString();` (And create a new `Uri` from the result)

Comment: please read the question again. I'd like to get the url and query string from within that page e.g. on page_load.