# Cannot pick query string variable from code behind

Tags: asp.net

URL: `http://localhost:11111/foldername/pagename.aspx#&&PORS=reactive&GridSortDirection=Ascending&GridPage=0&CJ=false&GridSortExpression=SiteReference&CN=na na`

Variable in Question :  CN with value na na

When I try below code I am getting null reference exception

```
string test = Request.QueryString["CN"].ToString();
```

Am I missing anything?

Note: in the above URL I have tried all variables such as PORS, GridSortDirection etc none of them are working.

Comment: Querystring is the content after the '?' in the URL. You have '#' instead of '?'. '#' is used to jump to the anchor on the same page.
URL should be like:
http://localhost:11111/foldername/pagename.aspx?PORS=reactive&GridSortDirection=Ascending&GridPage=0&CJ=false&GridSortExpression=SiteReference&CN=na na

Answer (score 0):

Querystring is the content after the '?' in the URL. You have '#' instead of '?'. '#' is used to jump to the anchor on the same page.

URL should be like:

```
URL= http://localhost:11111/foldername/pagename.aspx?PORS=reactive&GridSortDirection=Ascending&GridPage=0&CJ=false&GridSortExpression=SiteReference&CN=na na
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out its an anchor mark , i can only resolve it through javascript see the link for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322108/c-sharp-get-complete-url-with

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get. The URL in your question does not have '?', so are those anchors in your URL?

Comment: that's fine but the anchors are there for a reason, i cannot change the way URL is built just wanted to extract the values, but apparently i cannot from the code behind, see the URL i posted

Answer (score 0):

Your URL contains a **Page Fragment Identifier** (#). The browser does not send anything to the right of the # back to the server  (including the # itself). So there is no way for the server to make use of that information, unless you do something nonstandard like send it via an ajax call with javascript.